# books on htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

can any one suggest me good book for .htaccess which easily available in India, book may content all basic as well as higher levels of how to write htaccess.

Comment: I think that it's a great question. I can see why it doesn't belong on StackOverflow, but I still think that people should be allowed to look for recommended litterature to learn more. Why not use the experience from a million programmers to learn in the right way? I agree with this question and used the answer provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually download [The Definitive Guide to Apache mod_rewrite](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590595610) book.

However I find this [Apache mod_rewrite manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html) a very good reference point.

Comment: I never knew that someone wrote a book about mod_rewrite. Interesting :)

Comment: @anubhava Download link is broken can you have other names?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, links updated.